# Visual Studio editor is behaving weird! Showing compilation error with every instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

Whenever I compile any website in Visual Studio I face multiple compilation errors but code gets executed perfectly. I am supposing that some setting is changed with my vs editor.

Following are few error from list:

> Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start name character. D:\Gourav\WebSite1\Demo.aspx
>
> Character '%', hexadecimal value 0x25 is illegal in an XML name.
>
> The character '@', hexadecimal value 0x40 is illegal at the beginning of an XML name.
>
> Character '@', hexadecimal value 0x40 is illegal in an XML name.

Please help!!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing a bit more, but there's [a link here](http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/AspNet/Special%20Characters%20in%20AppSetting.aspx) about a trying to put a Regex in the web.config like this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SpecialCharacterRegEx" value="[~” # % & * :" < > ? / \ { | }]+"/>
</appSettings>
```

Which gives compilation errors like this:

```
1. Character ' ', hexadecimal value 0x20 is illegal in an XML name
2. Illegal syntax. Expecting valid start namecharacter
3. Application Configuration file"App.config" is invalid
```

The trick was to replace it with something like:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SpecialCharacterRegEx" value="[~&quot; # % &amp; * : &lt; &gt; ? / \ { | }]+"/>
</appSettings>
```

I'll bet your problem is something similar in Demo.aspx.

Comment: No it still exist after adding this setting in config file.Actually this is no related to particular website, this problem is for all website.. so i think this is related to Visual studio

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you add the setting. You have a similar issue, that is, somewhere in your Demo.aspx there is an unusual character which should be encoded, e.g., `&lt;` instead of `<`.